# mysqlbackup: ERROR: Opening of file /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1 failed. Error code: 13, Permission denied

Tags: mysql, bash, permissions, selinux, mysql-backup

Im trying to backup my database using mysqlbackup, but I keep getting this error and I don't know why is refering to a Permission denied error.

I already turned off SeLinux because I thought that would be the cause but there's nothing in the selinux log either, also I can log in to mysql using the normal command: mysql -uuser -ppassword.

The whole password with the output can be seen here: http://pastie.org/10798013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because MySQLBackup requires that it be run as root to access needed resources. Normally you would simply run `sudo mysqlbackup`, but I believe that this does not work by default for this program.

The quickest thing to do in this case, is run the command as the root user. To do this, all you need to do is open a terminal and type:

```
sudo -s
```

You will be prompted for your password, then the terminal will show `root@...` instead of the normal `user@...`. This indicates that you are now root.

Now you can execute your code again:

```
mysqlbackup --compress --user=root --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --backup-dir=/home/user/backup backup
```

Once done, remember to log out of root by simply typing `exit`. Remember, do not use the root user unless you have no other choice; it is easy to accidentally change important files/folders unless you are sure of what you are doing.

#### Learn More

It is worthwhile to understand more about logging in as root, and even adjusting the configuration so that `mysqlbackup` does not require root, so here are some links:

- [MySQLBackup Permission Denied (Unix & Linux - StackExchange)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276547/why-when-i-try-to-execute-a-program-as-normal-user-i-get-denied-and-when-i-exec/276553)
- [RootSudo (Ubuntu Wiki)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

Answer (score 1):

late response, but this precise error happens when trying to restore a differential/incremental backup when the mysql deamon is running

if you are able to connect to your database using the command
`mysql -uuser -ppassword`
then you're only able to restore full backups

if not, then you're able to restore differential/incremental backups, but no full

in other words: you should turn off your service ( net stop mysql-8.0 for me )